# A regular expression to find and replace a dynamic URL

Tags: regex, url, replace

I need to clean out 120,000 dynamic URLs from an XML file. How can I write a regular expression to look for a "?" character in a line and then remove that line (or replace it with a space)

Example of a line that would need to be deleted:

```
<url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20something&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete the whole line or just the part from the ? to the </url>?

Comment: What language do you want to do the replace in?

Comment: @Zxaos delete the entire line

Comment: What if your url tags break into the next line? Like this `<url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20somethi
ng&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>`

Comment: @dubesor XML is a markup language, not one in which you can modify files file with.

Comment: @dubesor - You really need to be more specific in your question because it has spawned so many answers in different languages and in different contexts which is waste of time for many of us. Considering that you have asked the question about removing that line and not limited to getting the regex, you need to specify in which language you intend to do this. Also please specify, in the question, if you need to just look for a line only with the "?" character OR a line with "?" inside url tags.

Comment: i should have been more specific. i'm going to be removing the lines from my giant XML file using notepad++ and its regex search and replace. so i suppose it's not really programming language specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would simply be:

```
<url>.*?\?.*?<\/url>
```

And if you wanna replace it in say C#, then:

```
  String sourcestring = "BlahBlahBlah\n<url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20something&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>\nBlah?BlahB?lah\nBlahBla?hBlah\n<url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20somethi\nng&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>\nBlahBlahBlah";
  String matchpattern = @"<url>.*?\?.*?<\/url>";
  String replacementpattern = @"";
  Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementpattern,RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline));
```

Please note that this would replace the url tags with space even if they break into the next line as shown in the sample text.

*Sample text before replace:*

- BlahBlahBlah
- <url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20something&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>
- Blah?BlahB?lah
- BlahBla?hBlah
- <url>http://www.website.com/order/index.asp?type=something%20somethi
- ng&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>

*Result text after replace:*

> BlahBlahBlah
>
> Blah?BlahB?lah BlahBla?hBlah
>
> BlahBlahBlah

---

**Update:**
If you are using Notepad++, you need to check the *matches newline* checkbox in the Find/Replace dialog (so that it matches overflowing lines of url tags because `.` in the regex does not match CR/LF.

The alternative would be using Ωmega's regex because it matches everything except for the characters in its class: `<url>[^<?]*\?[^<]*<\/url>`

Comment: @dubesor - You haven't picked the best solution. Using lazy operators in regex (such as `.*?`) hurts performance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `gsub` in ruby would do it.  For example to substitute a question mark for a space:

```
string_containing_urls = "<url>http://example.com?sdfhkldj</url>\n<url>http://example.com</url>"
string_containing_urls.gsub(/\?/, ' ') # => "<url>http://example.com sdfhkldj</url>\n<url>http://example.com</url>"
```

If you wanted to replace any url between `<url> ... </url>` tags with a space you could use the following:

```
string_containing_urls = "<url>http://example.com?sdfhkldj</url>\n<url>http://example.com</url>"
string_containing_urls.gsub(/<url>.*\?.*<\/url>/, ' ') # => " \n<url>http://example.com</url>"
```

The following would remove the entire line

```
string_containing_urls = "<url>http://example.com?sdfhkldj</url>\n<url>http://example.com</url>"
string_containing_urls.gsub(/<url>.*\?.*<\/url>\n/, '') # => "<url>http://example.com</url>"
```

Similar substitution functions are available in most any other language as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<url>[^<?]*\?[^<]*<\/url>` with empty string

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
(<url>http://[^?<]+)(\?[^<]*)(</url>)
```

Should work. If you want to just get rid of the dynamic part, substitute back in $1$3. If you want to drop the whole line, do

```
(<url>http://[^?<]+\?[^<]*</url>)
```

and substitute back in an empty string. If you're running it on a per-line basis, it just won't match anything without a '?'.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file called `input.txt` contains:

```
<urls>
     <url>http://www.google.com/search?type=something%20something&DisplayName=N&Material=blah</url>
     <url>http://www.yahoo.com/finance</url>
     <url>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions?type=somestuff</url>
     <url>http://www.facebook.com/person?type=someotherstuff</url>
     <url>http://www.amazon.com/order/index.asp</url>
</urls>
```

Use the [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) command:

```
sed '/<url>.*\?.*<\/url>/d' input.txt >> output.txt
```

Then the output will be:

```
<urls>
     <url>http://www.yahoo.com/finance/</url>
     <url>http://www.amazon.com/order/index.asp</url>
</urls>
```

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear. i'm not trying to remove the part after the "?", but actually the whole line (any line that contains a dynamic URL)

Comment: This example does just that. Notice any line which contained a "?" has been removed.

Comment: Assuming just one URL per line (and ignoring the fact that this pretends to be XML), `fgrep -v '?' file >newfile` removes all lines with a question mark.